# Accessing Native Contact List

Tags: cordova

I am trying to fetch the Contacts from the phone through my Application (based on HTML5 , JqueryMobile and PhoneGap) . I am filtering initially the Contacts by Name , i mean hardcoded the name so its filtering the name , but not fetching the number through this Native Application. I think there is some problem accessing the contact list. Can Somebody help me out over this with some code . I am applying the following JavaScript for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="John"; 
   alert("options.filter = "+options.filter);
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
  //  var fields_number = ["displayNumber","number"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);


}

      // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {
//alert("Success");
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        alert("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        alert("Display Number = " + contacts[i].displayNumber);
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, I have tested on iOS,Android and Blackberry devices.

```
var filter = ["id","displayName", "name"];
var options = new ContactFindOptions(); 
options.filter= "John";
options.multiple= true; 
navigator.contacts.find(   filter , 
function(contacts){
          console.log("contacts found::");
          console.log(contacts);                                                  
}, function(error){
    console.log("Contacts Error : "+error);
},options);
```

Comment: Are you able to fetch the Number of the Same contact From the Native Contact List ?

Comment: Yes i am able to fetch the contact list. Make sure when you are trying  to use for android you need to give proper permission in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

to display phoneNumbers, the correct way is to use a "for" like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){ contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value }
```